# r: combining foreach results

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am running a parallel process in a `foreach` loop that returns a 7x30 matrix at the end of each loop.  When I run the loop using this command, it finishes in 11.5 minutes:

```
myData<-foreach(i=1:270000, .packages='quadprog')%dopar%{
```

Unfortunately, myData is a list and I want to plot the last two columns of every matrix within that list.  So, I use this command to convert it to a data frame for `ggplot2`:

```
myData<-Reduce(rbind.data.frame, myData[1:length(myData)])
```

This command works well for a small myData but myData is 270,000 matrices long.  It is either hanging up or taking a really long time to convert.

So, I try to run the loop using this command so that the output is a data frame in the first place:

```
myData<-foreach(i=1:270000, .combine=rbind.data.frame, .packages='quadprog')%dopar%{
```

This has been running for the last two hours (way longer than 11 minutes).

Is there a way to efficiently get the output from these loops and put it into a format where I can graph it?

Interestingly, when I look at the Windows Task Manager, the first call to the loop immediately sends all of my CPU core usage to 100%.  The second one is closer to 10% even though I setup the same number of clusters under `doSnow`.

Answer (score 0):

use rbindlist instead of rbind to combine your results and .multicombine to speed it up

```
comb = function(...)rbindlist(...)
myData = foreach(i = 1:27000 , .combine = comb ,.packages='quadprog',.multicombine = TRUE) %dopar% {
```